# No value displayed in the text field

Tags: ios, uislider

when i scroll the UISlider, i want to display the current value in UITextField, however i see the following string `nan` instead of the numeric value of the slider, can you help me please :

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender 
{ 
    nomDeStationTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", [sender value]]; 
}
```

the connections in IB are correct, also, the min value for the slider is 0.0 and the max one is 70, i need to display the current position (i.e : 20) in the UItextField

Comment: Have you actually tried something like @"%f" ? And is the textfield connected in IB?

Comment: when i try %f, i got always the value 0.0000000

Comment: Can you dump the class of the sender and try to dump the value to console of the slider in a button event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the sender to UISlider:

```
nomDeStationTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", [(UISlider *)sender value]];
```